Selecting a certificate in the CryptoPro Extension for Code Browser Plug-in window using selenium
I am trying to automate work with resources that require authentication when logging in with a certificate. I use python + selenium==4.24.0. Authentication takes place using the CryptoPro Extension for Code Browser Plug-in browser extension https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cryptopro-extension-for-c/iifchhfnnmpdbibifmljnfjhpififfog?hl=ru.
image here
An authorization window pops up when you log in. I can't figure out how to manage this window in selenium. I need to select a user and click ok. The window pops up before the page loads.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

browser_app = '/usr/bin/chromium-gost'
chrome_driver = 'data/chromium_gost/chromedriver'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = browser_app


driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(chrome_driver))
driver.get('https://resourse/address')


I tried to use alert and Mouse actions
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/
But it didn't help the page continues to wait for action
